# Alternative to using turtle.goto() in Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, goto

This program creates a bouncing ball using `turtle.goto()`, is there an alternative?

```
from random import *
from turtle import *
from base import vector

# The ball is drawn, the actions are used from the base file
def draw():
  ball.move(aim)
  x = ball.x
  y = ball.y

  if x < -200 or x > 200:
      aim.x = -aim.x

  if y < -200 or y > 200:
      aim.y = -aim.y

  clear()
  # Can this program serve a purpose without it?
  goto(x, y)
  dot(10, 'blue')
  ontimer(draw,50)
```

Generally, what is the point of having a `goto()` function?

Comment: Is there a problem with your current implementation? What happens when you take out the `goto` call? Is there a particular reason that `goto` is not meeting your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a bouncing ball without using `turtle.goto()`, here's a rough example:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def draw():
    ball.forward(10)
    x, y = ball.position()

    if not (-200 < x < 200 and -200 < y < 200):
        ball.undo()  # undo 'forward()'
        ball.setheading(ball.heading() + 90)
        ball.forward(10)

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(draw, 50)

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

box = Turtle('square')
box.hideturtle()
box.fillcolor('white')
box.shapesize(20)
box.stamp()

ball = Turtle('circle')
ball.color('blue')
ball.setheading(30)
ball.penup()

draw()

screen.exitonclick()
```